# Why didn't the SSS create powers like Tachibana Kanade (Tenshi) did?

Tags: angel-beats

I saw *Angel Beats* a couple of years ago (can't really remember when), and I remember that Tenshi

> created her powers with a software program.

So why didn't the SSS create powers themselves to fight her, if they were later on shown to be able to create weapons out of dirt?

Comment: Maybe because they couldn't? Either they didn't have that software, or they simply didn't know how to use it? When I was still at school, I was one of the few who knew how to write code. Maybe it's a similar principle? Like how there's only one person in the anime who can play the guitar, for instance?

Answer (score 3):

If they remember how to do it, they can create weapons.

Also, at some point they can try to create things they don't remember (for example, the cannon at guild basement).

Probably, one or two people from the guild remember weapons, and they instruct the others.

For creating skills (power, abilities, body weapons), they need to know how to code and have a computer. They can get a computer from the computer room #1, but they also need the Angel Player software and a programmer (and apparently, only Takeyama knows how to do it).

Also, you don't know if the Angel Player is a software from the afterlife, or a software created by Tenshi. Maybe, the software itself is more difficult to create.

Lastly, if I remember correctly, Tenshi is the longest afterlife inhabitant.

Comment: Plus, you'd need access to the Angel Player software in the first place. Angel Player wasn't exactly easy-to-find – it was created by the elusive Programmer.

Comment: The software was also written in English – making it difficult to interpret.